# Как можно посмотреть все существующие страницы в WordPress

Tags: wordpress

ситуация такова:
Захожу вчера на сайт в админку и вижу 2 новых коммента, посмотрел на них и вроде бы все норм, но только комментарий оставили на странице (например) "тунец".
Думаете, что тут необычного, но необычное тут то что у меня нет страницы "тунец", а вот кто то на нее зашел (и даже не один) и оставил там комметарий.
Пробежался по меткам, все метки пишутся через [https://siteurl.com/метки/слаг_метки](https://siteurl.com/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8)
Смотрел и страницы и категории (да что я только не смотрел), разве только в БД не лазил.
Подскажите плагин или сниппет который вывел бы мне все существующие страницы (имею ввиду всех типов и классов), желательно, что бы ими можно было управлять, удалять и т.д.

Comment: Обновите ядро WordPress и все плагины и не используйте нуленые темы/плагины, все записи хранятся в таблице `wp_posts` - проще смотреть туда, чем ставить еще один ненужный плагин.

Comment: Дело в том, что это случилось как раз таки после обновления ядра и плагинов, просто увидел не сразу.